# C# asp.net update gridview value without page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am looking for a way to update gridview value without page refresh, I used updatepanel and it works fine when I am using BoundField but when I use ItemTemplate with label the data of the gridview disappear when I click update button and I need to refresh the page to get the updated data back.

and if I didn't use updatepanel the data will not disappear but it will not be updated without page refresh.

```
protected void button_1(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{

            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= DESKTOP-U9437PU; initial Catalog = Mydb; Integrated Security =True;"))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select stat_id from requests_table where  req_id ='1'", sqlCon))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Label_stat2.Text = reader["stat_id"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }

                if (Label_stat2.Text == "1")
                {

                    string sql = "update requests_table set stat_id = '2' where req_id ='" 1 "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                    sqlCon.Close();

            GridView1.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel2.Update();


                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
            GridView1.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel2.Update();

        }

        else
        {
         //do nothing

        }
}
```

Markup:

```
                                   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

                                   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">

                                   <ContentTemplate>




                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  CssClass="datatable"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True"  PageSize="5"  
                         AllowSorting="True" EnableViewState="false"><Columns >

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, req_id%>" SortExpression="req_id">
                            <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:Label ID="req_id" runat="server"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, req_subject%>" SortExpression="req_subject">
                            <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:Label ID="req_subject" runat="server"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, req_priority%>" SortExpression="priority_id">
                            <ItemTemplate >

                     <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Button ID="ButtonUnder1"  runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("req_id") %>' CssClass="my_btn" OnClick="button_1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick = "Confirm2()"   />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>


                        </Columns>

                           <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="Bottom" PageButtonCount="5" NextPageText=">>" PreviousPageText="<<" />


        </asp:GridView>



              </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You have the UpdateMode set to Conditional, with ChildrenAsTriggers set to false, and no explicit triggers defined. It therefore doesn't have anything set to do an asynchronous postback. You need to change one of those in order to have it work as you want. However: you'll be far better off just ditching the GridView and using a proper client side library to render your table and fetch data asynchronously from the server. Web Forms just doesn't handle this very well.

Comment: Do you know if the code behind is firing at all, as suggested you have updatemode set to false. You may want to look to see if the datasource is lost. If so just add it. Currently you are binding the gridview but you have not set what with.